# How to display content from PHP to html

Tags: php, html

So what i'am trying to do is that I have a PHP page that gets the ID for some text stored in a database (Varchar) and I wish to display this content in my HTML page. So I can update the content in the database and the edit take effect across the site. 
PHP:

```
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  // do some validation here to ensure id is safe

  $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
  mysql_select_db("images");
  $sql = "SELECT review FROM reviews WHERE id=$id";
  $result = mysql_query("$sql");
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  mysql_close($link);

  echo $row['review'];
```

I wish to display the content where is says "PHP content here"
HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="albumModal1">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <!-- Top right close X -->
        <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
            <span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"</span>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p class="modalTitle">The Beatles: Abby Road</p>
                        <img src="beatles.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block albumImgGrey">
                        <!-- Album 1's Review -->
                        <div class="modalText">
                            <p>Content upon content upon more content 
                                <p>upon more content</p>
                                Content upon content upon more content 
                                <p>upon more content</p>
                                <div class="starcolor">
                                    <span>&#9733 &#9733 &#9733 &#9733 &#9733</span>
                                </div>
                            </p>
                            <!-- PHP content here....... -->
                            <!-- PHP content here....... -->
                            <!-- Bottom of the review links -->
                            <ul class="list-inline item-details">
                                <li> 
                                    Year of release: <strong><a href="#">3000</a></strong>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    Previous Album: <strong><a href="#">Hippie tree</a></strong>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    Following Album: <strong><a href="#">Backup Plus++</a></strong>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Put `<?php echo $row['review']; ?>` there. Any tutorial on creating HTML content from PHP should show how to do this.

Comment: Please use PDO or mysqli for your database access and learn about prepared statements. Your code could be open to attack depending on your "validation to ensure id is safe"

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the input. The PHP file is an external file called getreview.php and the HTML if for my index.

Comment: Maybe you should be using AJAX to get the content from the server, and then insert it into the place in the HTML file using Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code:

```
<?php echo $row['review'];?>
```

where you have **PHP content here**, ensure you include the PHP tags.

**STOP USING THE MYSQL EXTENSION, A KITTEN AND TWO PUPPIES DIE ANYTIME YOU DO THIS**

Learn pdo or mysqli instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your database result in a php file and then Web server will parse that php code and generate the required output.

It should be like.

**output.php**

```
<?php
<div class="modal fade" id="albumModal1">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
    <!-- Top right close X -->
    <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
        <span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"</span>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p class="modalTitle">The Beatles: Abby Road</p>
                    <img src="beatles.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block albumImgGrey">
                    <!-- Album 1's Review -->
                    <div class="modalText">
                        <p>Content upon content upon more content 
                            <p>upon more content</p>
                            Content upon content upon more content 
                            <p>upon more content</p>
                            <div class="starcolor">
                                <span>&#9733 &#9733 &#9733 &#9733 &#9733</span>
                            </div>
                        </p>
                        <!-- PHP content here....... -->
                        $id = $_GET['id'];
                        $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
                        mysql_select_db("images");
                        $sql = "SELECT review FROM reviews WHERE id=$id";
                        $result = mysql_query("$sql");
                        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
                        mysql_close($link);
                        echo $row['review'];
                        <!-- PHP content here....... -->
                        <!-- Bottom of the review links -->
                        <ul class="list-inline item-details">
                            <li> 
                                Year of release: <strong><a href="#">3000</a></strong>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                Previous Album: <strong><a href="#">Hippie tree</a></strong>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                Following Album: <strong><a href="#">Backup Plus++</a></strong>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="modal-dialog"> <div class="modal-content"> <!-- Top right close X --> <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"</span> </div> <div class="container"> <div class="row"> <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2"> <div class="modal-body"> <p class="modalTitle">The Beatles: Abby Road</p> <img src="beatles.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block albumImgGrey"> <!-- Album 1's Review --> <div class="modalText"> <p>Content upon content upon more content <p>upon more content</p> Content upon content upon more content <p>upon more content</p> <div class="starcolor"> <span>&#9733 &#9733 &#9733 &#9733 &#9733</span> </div> </p> <!-- PHP content here....... --> <!-- PHP content

<?php echo $row['content']; ?>

 here....... --> <!-- Bottom of the review links --> <ul class="list-inline item-details"> <li> Year of release: <strong><a href="#">3000</a></strong> </li> <li> Previous Album: <strong><a href="#">Hippie tree</a></strong> </li> <li> Following Album: <strong><a href="#">Backup Plus++</a></strong> </li> </ul> </div> <div class="modal-footer"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div>
```